# Why is the margin above the footer smaller than the rest?

Tags: html, css

Recently I've been messing around with web-design and I wrote a simple CSS-based template in a simple text editor (Notepad++). I've ran into a problem where the margin for above the footer is smaller than the rest of the div boxes in my template. This troubles me because **I use the same div class that defines the margin for all of the div boxes**. So please help me out. I've been stuck on this for a few days now.

**Here is what the site looks like:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqQkn.png

**Here is the index HTML file:** http://pastebin.com/xAcMhuF0

**Here is the main CSS file:** http://pastebin.com/efAbr2EM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear doesn't work with margin. Use this for the footer:

```
position: relative;
top: 100px; /* whatever value you need */
```

This will move the footer down 100px in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wonder why `clear` doesn't work with margin and padding.